# Temporary tables in hana

Tags: database, hana, hana-sql-script

it it possible to write script in hana that crate temporary table that is based

on existing table (with no need to define columns and columns types hard coded ):

```
 create local temporary table #mytemp (id integer, name varchar(20));
```

create temporary table with the same columns definitions and contain the 
same data ? if so ..i ill be glad to get some examples

i am searching the internet for 2 days and i couldn't find anything useful

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Creating local temporary tables based on dynamic structure definition is not supported in SQLScript.

The question would be: for what do you want to use it?
Instead of a local temp. table you can use a table variable in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

By querying sys.table_columns view, you can get the list and properties of source table and build a dynamic CREATE script then Execute to create the table.
You can find SQL codes for a sample case at [Create Table Dynamically on HANA Database](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/create-table-dynamically-using-sqlscript-on-sap-hana-database.aspx)

For table columns read

```
select * from sys.table_columns where table_name = 'TABLENAME';
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work in the hana version I have. I'm not sure how to find out what the version.

```
PROCEDURE "xxx.yyy.zzz::MY_TEST"(

    OUT "OUT_COL" NVARCHAR(200) 
)
   LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
   SQL SECURITY INVOKER
   AS
BEGIN
    create LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE #LOCALTEMPTABLE 
    as
    (
    SELECT distinct 'Cola' as out_col 
        FROM "SYNONYMS1"
    );
    select * from #LOCALTEMPTABLE ;
    DROP TABLE #LOCALTEMPTABLE;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The newer HANA version (HANA 2 SPS 04 Patch 5 ( Build 4.4.17 )) supports your request:

```
create local temporary table #tempTableName' like "tableTypeName";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should inherit the data types and all exact values from whatever query is in the parenthesis:

```
CREATE LOCAL COLUMN TEMPORARY TABLE #mytemp AS (
    SELECT 
    "COLUMN1",
    "COLUMN2",
    "COLUMN3"
    FROM MyTable 
    );
 -- Now you can add the rest of your query here as such: 
SELECT * FROM #mytemp
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can just write :

`create column table  #MyTempTable as ( select * from MySourceTable);`

BR,